# SIM Card for vacation in the US

Tags: usa, cellphones, data-plans, roaming

I will be visiting New York for about 10 days. I have an iPhone 4S (unlocked).

What are my options to have a sim card, preferably with data?

I probably won't use voice that much, but want to be able to make a call if needed.

Comment: AT&T pay as you go is a good option..

Answer (score 0):

US T-mobile offers pay as you go plans for SIM card phones. I believe the card costs $10, 1 day of unlimited voice and texts and 500 MB costs $3, and you can buy scratch-off refills at many convenience stores or pay for more time over over the phone with a credit card. If you use up 500MB you still get data, just at a a much lower speed. I do not think there are any ID requirements.

[This](http://www.t-mobile.com/bring-your-own-phone.html?cm_mmc=PaidSearch-_-DirectResponse-_-Google-_-DR-Brand&cm_mmca1=s&cm_mmca2=%2btmobile%20sim%20card%20plan&cm_mmca3=b&gclid=CM_dja7r-rgCFYl_Qgod70MAyA) should help.

Comment: 3 USD a day for 500MB? That sounds weird. How would you use those? You get 500MB a month for about 15 USD in Germany.

Comment: Buy the SIM from T-Mo, buy a card to add USD to the SIM, call the # on the back of the card to add the USD. Call/text/use data and they deduct $3 from the account for 24 hours of use. It's 500 MB of high speed and then you get kicked down to lower speed for the remainder of your 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Still, it sounds awfully expensive. Prepaid mobile network is *a lot* cheaper in Europe.

Comment: Well, yeah. As is the internet in general. Different market, different geography.